# 32nd+ sixteenth +quarter notes

Tags: theory, practice, learning, saxophone

I have doing questions here on this website, and I learned so much but some examples look hard to understand.
In this example how can I count?
Thanks [image]

Comment: Take everything down to its smallest note value, or sometimes as here, semiquavers. So count semis - which will amount to 16. Count 1&2& up to 16. That covers everything.1st note counts 1&2& next is 3&, next is 4&.

Comment: Is this during a cadenza of some sort?

Comment: This looks like a typical cadenza of a cornet solo.

Don’t count too much, and don’t try to analyze this passage, it doesn’t fit in any time measure.

Answer (score 3):

This is a soloist cadenza, like Richard assumes in his comment.

- The first motif of this is equal to a quarter note: one 8th and two 16th - and easy to count.
- The 2nd passage the E-major scale down has in the beginning a 16th note and two 32nds, which don’t match in a metrical schema - if you don’t notate it as duplets of six 32nds. So don’t try to find any system of time, you can play them ad lib. like the succeeding passage with no accent - except on the D#.
- The 3 eight notes are no triplets, you can play them as slowly as you like. There will be surely a rit. on ths triad to make some tension before the fermata.
- The descending staccato is to interpret in the same way: Don’t count, play expressive and adapted to your technical abilities (embouchure, breathing etc.)